# Symfony - Custom bundle best pratices

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

The [Symfony website](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#actions-and-controllers) says :

> Actions are usually very short - **around 10-15 lines of code** - because
>   they just call other parts of the application to get or generate the
>   needed information and then they render a template to show the results
>   to the user.

In my case, I made a custom bundle with multiple method like :

```
public function customAction()
{

    // getting Request data, clean it, sanitize it = ~ 15 lines
    // getting a file from local storage, then control it = ~ 10 lines
    // Executing DB queries (select, insert) with entity manager = ~ 25 lines

    etc...

}
```

My question is simple : where to locate my whole codes if all the xxxAction() methods inside a controller should stay fit and short ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is that actions only dispatch something between the request and your application logic - this logic itself should reside in services that are reusable and not directly coupled to an action.

So: gather all needed data from your request in the **action** and call a method from another **service** with all needed data

Comment: Thanks, you're right it's much better to store the logic in service(s).